# non-UTF8 characters in $PATH interferes with Homebrew Mac

Tags: ruby, terminal, homebrew

`echo $PATH` produces this result

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Perl:/Library/Python:/Library/TeX/texbin:Vim�UnDo�:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
```

It appears that the non-UTF8 characters interfere with my homebrew commands. No matter which homebrew command I type I get the following:

```
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/PATH.rb:93:in `split': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
```

I have tried to delete everything in .zshrc file. I have also tried to reinstall homebrew. None of these work. I can't even delete Homebrew to install a fresh one. I also cannot find the `Vim�UnDo�' anywhere. I suspect it has something to do with 'Vim�UnDo�'? However, any ruby script I have created works.

Comment: You could check if the `UnDo` string is still present in some of your rc-files with `grep -d skip UnDo ~/.*`.

Comment: Need to delete directory from $PATH. See [solutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108873/removing-a-directory-from-path)

Comment: Also if you have modified your Bash or Zsh rc files you have to restart your terminal at minimum for the changes to take effect. May even require you to log out of your desktop and log back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manually went into my `.zshrc` file and removed those characters from my `$PATH` variable.